# Tkinter can't append labels to lists?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, configure

```
labels = []
global labels
#blablbalabla code
welcome = Tkinter.Label(root,text= "Welcome to Fobby").place(x=250,y=250)
labels.append(welcome)
print labels
>>> [None]
```

What is wrong? Are labels an incompatible class with lists?

Comment: Do not use `global` like that. The `global` statement, *when needed*, should be used inside functions and classes, not at the module level(where it has no effect). It is used to mark that a variable is not local but global(at module level local == global and thus it does nothing).

Comment: Was getting started with python back then, they should honestly take my syntax choices and display them in a museum or something :p

Comment: @madprogramer  Did you just go on a 4-year hiatus from 2013-2017, then came back and saw that comment?  lol

Comment: @NoName it wasn't a hiatus so much as "high school" but yeah. I just moved on to other things I guess. Kudos to you for noticing (^_^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `place()` returns None:

```
labels = []
welcome = Tkinter.Label(root,text= "Welcome to Fobby")
welcome.place(x=250,y=250)
labels.append(welcome)
print labels
```